# Как отобразить диски в QListView?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

Опишу проблему:
Мне необходимо в менеджере графических файлов создать возврат к родительской папке и... списку дисков.
И реализовать это в виджете `QListView` без использования других виджетов (что-бы не загромождать код и интерфейс).
Что реализовано на данный момент:

- возврат к родительской папке

  ```
   def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, e):
   fp = self.mdl.fileInfo(self.currentIndex()).filePath() # получаем путь куда даблкликнули
   if fp.endswith('.png'): # <-- если файл (у меня картинки пнг) то ничего не делаем
       pass
   elif fp.endswith('/..'): # <-- если /.. то устанавливаем индекс из указанного пути
       self.setRootIndex(self.mdl.index(fp))
   else: # <-- если что-то другое, то тоже индекс из пути (вход в другие папки)
       self.setRootIndex(self.mdl.index(fp))
  ```

**Визуально выглядит так:**

[image: внешний вид QListView]

Я знаю как вывести список дисков в `QListView`, достаточно вместо пути вставить пустую строку:

```
self.setRootIndex(self.mdl.index(''))
```

**И тогда получим:**

[image: отображаются диски]

**Но!!!** Если мы кликаем по каталогам выше и выше, то выходим в корневой каталог (типа диск C:/) **в котором нет спецсимвола ".."**

[image: нет спец символа ".."]

***Что можно сделать что бы символ ".." отображался в корневом каталоге для возможности перехода к дискам?
Или как реализовать переход из корневого каталога к дискам без применения дополнительных виджетов?***

---

Дополнение к вопросу (минимальный воспроизводимый код):

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QListView
from PyQt5.Qt import QFileSystemModel, QDir
from PyQt5.QtCore import QSize

class MyFileManager(QListView):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.mdl = QFileSystemModel()
        self.mdl.setRootPath(QDir.rootPath())
        self.mdl.setFilter(QDir.Drives | QDir.AllDirs | QDir.Files)

        self.setModel(self.mdl)
        self.setRootIndex(self.mdl.index(QDir.currentPath()))

        self.setViewMode(QListView.IconMode)
        self.setMovement(QListView.Snap)
        self.setGridSize(QSize(96, 96))
        self.setIconSize(QSize(64, 64))

    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, e):
        fp = self.mdl.fileInfo(self.currentIndex()).filePath()

        print(self.rootIndex())
        if fp.endswith('.png'):
            pass
        elif fp.endswith('/..'):
            self.setRootIndex(self.mdl.index(fp)) # <--- в родительский каталог
        elif fp.endswith('/.'):
            self.setRootIndex(self.mdl.index('')) # <--- к списку дисков
        else:
            self.setRootIndex(self.mdl.index(fp)) # <--- в текущий или дочерний каталог

if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = MyFileManager()
    w.resize(400, 700)
    w.move(100, 100)
    w.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve]

Comment: Дополнил. Самый последний блок кода минимальный и воспроизводимый.

Comment: Перенаследуй QFilesystemModel и добавь элемент перехода к дискам